# Best way to cache/reuse json object

Tags: java, json, jvm, jvm-crash

Recently, we have issues with some of our production JVMs which is going for GC very frequently and taking long gc pause as well. After looking into the heap dump it seems a new class introduced in recent build storing large number of product data in json object causing this.

This class basically gets the data from multiple sources and build the json object based on that. **We can see these json objects are getting saved as char[] in heap space which is taking almost 25% of space. The problem is this class creating json object every time whenever method is getting called. So, for same product it's creating multiple json objects and filling up heap space quickly.**

[image]

We may need to use some type of caching but there are large number of products in site.Any suggestion how we can handle this issue in a better way?

Comment: `-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication`

Comment: Very good point but we are using JDK 7. I think this flag available after Java 8 update 20.

Comment: Sure, but you should compare every effort of any proposed solution with the effort of just updating the JRE to get this for free…